# RaspberryPI I2C do not detect any address

Tags: raspberry-pi, config, i2c, master-slave

I2C on my Pi(s) is not detecting any slave.

I am obviously missing something here, the PI's I2C is "working" but do not detect the device. I did (and redid) everytghing suggested by Sirajo on [I2C not detecting ? issues in hardware or any other?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42904712/i2c-not-detecting-issues-in-hardware-or-any-other#new-answer)

The I2C devices tested are : `NCD9830`(chip only) ; `HT16K33`(adafruit) ; LCD with `PCF8574`.

The hardware has been verified ; 
The i2c lines has been probed in order to verify if pull-up "hold the line too hard" and I do get nice square signal.

Nothing is ever showing up.
If I ask ...

```
    $ ls /dev/*i2c*
```

I get ...

```
    /dev/i2c-1
```

therefore the i2c1 is active

If I ask ...

```
$ sudo i2cdetect -y -1
```

I do get the table but NO I2C address showing up.

What is the missing part ?

Comment: I'm having the same issue with my pi 4B, it used to show the default address of 27, but after batteries got low one time now the i2c stopped working and the sudo i2cdetect -y -1 shows an empty table with no I2C address. Did you ever solve this?

Comment: @TheRealZing I'm facing the exact same issue. Did youuu solve it?  I have four RPi 4b's, and the only one that shows any i2C issue is the one that has a battery pack. The com doesn't pick up any devices (not even RPi stock onboard devices).