# i2cdetect does not recognize VL6180X sensors behind TCA9548A I2C multiplexer

Tags: raspberry-pi, i2c, multiplexing

I have 2 VL6180X Distance Sensors properly connected to a TCA9548A Multiplexer, however it only recognizes the Multiplexer itself and not the 2 sensors as you can see with the 0x70. Is there any way to configure the i2c adresses?

```
i2cdetect -y 1
```

gives me the following output

```
     0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  a  b  c  d  e  f
00:          -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
10: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
20: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
30: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
40: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
50: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
60: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
70: 70 -- -- -- -- -- -- --
```

Ofc, I did already search the web to find a solution for it:

I installed

```
sudo apt-get install -y python-smbus
sudo apt-get install -y i2c-tools
```

I enabled i2c in the kernel (https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/66145/raspberry-pi-3-not-detecting-i2c-device)

Added everything to config.txt as in here:
[I2C not detecting ? issues in hardware or any other?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42904712/i2c-not-detecting-issues-in-hardware-or-any-other)

Comment: You have to enable I2C multiplexer *driver* in the kernel followed by enabling drivers for your sensors. If there is no driver you have to write one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to have the VL6180X properly instantiated behind a mux in Linux you should describe them in device tree. Have a look at the [I2C MUX documentation](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/i2c/i2c-topology.html).

Thus you should describe the whole setup (I2C mux + 2x VL6180X) like this:

```
&i2c1 { // the SoC bus controller
    mux@70 {
        compatible = "nxp,pca9548";
        reg = <0x70>;
        #address-cells = <1>;
        #size-cells = <0>;

        i2c@3 {
            #address-cells = <1>;
            #size-cells = <0>;
            reg = <3>;

            gpio1: gpio@29 {
                compatible = "st,vl6180";
                reg = <0x29>;
            };
        };

        i2c@4 {
            #address-cells = <1>;
            #size-cells = <0>;
            reg = <4>;

            gpio1: gpio@29 {
                compatible = "st,vl6180";
                reg = <0x29>;
            };
        };
    };
};
```

This will instantiate  two new busses (list them with `i2cdetect -l`) and one  vl6180 sensor will appear under each of them and be described as regular IIO devices.

The above code is a simple mix of device tree binding documentation for [i2c-mux](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/Documentation/devicetree/bindings/i2c/i2c-mux.txt) and for the [VL6180X sensor](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/Documentation/devicetree/bindings/iio/light/vl6180.txt), available in the kernel sources.

Answer (score 1):

Luca's answer is better than this, though this should still work.

It doesn't work like that. You can't *"see"* the attached devices through the multiplexer.

Instead, you open the multiplexer and write a *"control byte"* to it, to tell it which device it should forward the following data to.

Comment: okay, good to know that. thanks for your help!

how do I send a control byte? do you have a code snippet example?

Comment: Better than that, there's a little tutorial here... https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruit-tca9548a-1-to-8-i2c-multiplexer-breakout/wiring-and-test